# SPARQL help to build modify query

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have to add a few new fields to existing report. Our system already have a lot of reports with types AccountTeamBodReport, CoordinatorBodReport. Also I want to set default value for new fields.

```
PREFIX  :     <http://example.com/knowledge-black-belt#>
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

INSERT { ?s  :hasResult "" ; //(new fields)
        :hasResultPriority "MEDIUM";
        :hasLowMarginComments "";
        :hasLowMarginCommentsPriority "MEDIUM";

}
WHERE
    { ?s rdf:type    ?type ;

FILTER ( ?type IN (:AccountTeamBodReport, :CoordinatorBodReport) )
}
```

It doesn't work. There is any errors. What I did wrong? I use fuseki server and check all my query there. Fuseki logs have only successful responds. When I want to see specific report I use:

```
PREFIX  :     <http://dataart.com/knowledge-black-belt#>
PREFIX  xsd:  <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT *
WHERE
 { ?s  :hasId                ?name ;
    rdf:type              ?type ;
    :hasCreationTime      ?created ;
    :hasReportMonth       ?reportMonth ;
    :hasAchievements      ?achievements ;
    :hasAchievementsPriority  ?achievementsPriority ;
    :hasRisksIssues       ?risksIssues ;
    :hasRisksIssuesPriority  ?risksIssuesPriority ;
    :hasOther             ?other ;
    :hasOtherPriority     ?otherPriority ;
    :hasPerformance       ?performance ;
    :hasCustomerRelationship  ?customerRelationship ;
    :hasTeamMorale        ?teamMorale ;
    :hasNoNews            ?noNews ;
    :hasResult            ?result ; 
    :hasResultPriority    ?resultPriority;
    :hasLowMarginComments ?lowMarginComments;
    :hasLowMarginCommentsPriority ?lowMarginCommentsPriority;
    :hasClient ?client
OPTIONAL
  { ?s  :hasIndicatorDescription  ?indicatorDescription}
 ?s  rdf:type    ?type ;
    :hasClient :clientSomeId


FILTER ( ?type IN (:AccountTeamBodReport, :CoordinatorBodReport) )
}
```

And there is any changes after Insert query.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is **not** meaningful ... error, unexpected changes, no changes ... ?

Comment: For debugging, you could also first check whether the WHERE clause matches any data by using a SELECT query.

Comment: Sorry, amended.

Comment: Does your select query match data, i.e. is the result not empty?

Comment: Not empty, I have object without data from Insert query

Comment: Sorry, I cannot follow you: the `WHERE` part of your `INSERT` query. If you put it into a `SELECT` query, does it return results for `?s`? Next, how do you perform the SPARQL Update request?

Comment: I updated my question. I used two different query. In first way I have result without any changes, second - 3 new object and old object hasn't been deleted

Comment: This does **not** answer my questions...I told you to check whether the `WHERE` part returns any answer when you use it in a `SELECT` query!

Comment: Yes. After INSERT query, SELECT query returns me 1 old object and 15 new objects with various variants new fields filled. In result I have 16 objects.

Comment: What? That's not what I'm asking. One more time, what is exactly is not working?

Comment: I have existing report with some fields in DB. I want to add new fields with default values to this report. When I execute INSERT query that I specified in my question, in result instead of one report with new fields I have 1 old report(not changed) and 15 new reports(rows) with the same old fields AND in each has various variants new fields filled. The last row has all correctly filled fields. As I understood INSERT query executes 15 times.

Comment: It adds exactly as many "rows" as the `WHERE` part matches the data. Again, and please try to understand what I said several times, use the `WHERE` part of your `INSERT` query und do a `SELECT` query with it **before** you're doing the `INSERT` . Then you'll see which data matches, each row resulting in a new entry.

Comment: WHERE returns me 1 objects before insert,cause my local database's integrity was broken a lot of times) so, I create test report, use for him Insert query and have something

Comment: IF the `SELECT` query returns only 1 row then there will be only one `?s` added with all the values that you specified. I still don't get the problem.

Comment: I also thought that.

Comment: That doesn't make sense - please run `SELECT * {?s ?p ?o}` before the INSERT. If the data is already there, you have to start with a fresh database